# Google Guice, Interceptors and PrivateModules

Tags: module, guice, private

New poster here, hope I don't brake any rules :)

I am using PrivateModule in google-guice in order to have multiple DataSource's for the same environment. But I am having a hard time getting MethodInterceptor's to work inside the private modules.
Below is a simple test case that explains the "problem".

A simple service class would be:

```
interface Service {
    String go();
}

class ServiceImpl implements Service {

    @Override @Transactional
    public String go() {
        return "Test Case...";
    }

}
```

The `MyModule` class would be:

```
class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        install(new PrivateModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(Service.class).to(ServiceImpl.class);
                bindInterceptor(
                    Matchers.any(),
                    Matchers.annotatedWith(Transactional.class),
                    new MethodInterceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation i)
                            throws Throwable {
                        System.out.println("Intercepting: "
                                + i.getMethod().getName());
                        return i.proceed();
                    }
                });
                expose(Service.class);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And the final test case:

```
public class TestCase {

    @Inject Service service;

    public TestCase() {
        Guice.createInjector(new MyModule()).injectMembers(this);
    }

    public String go() {
        return service.go();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestCase t = new TestCase();
        System.out.println(t.go());
    }

}
```

You would expect the output to be:

```
Intercepting: go
Test Case...
```

But it doesn't happen, the interceptor is not used, ant only `Test Case...` is output.

If I bind/expose the `ServiceImpl` instead of the interface then it works.

Thanks in advance,
Regards,
LL

Answer (score 0):

Well... I figured it out shortly after I posted the question :)

The problem is that you also need to `expose()` the `ServiceImpl` class.
So the bind/expose would be.

```
bind(ServiceImpl.class); // ServiceImpl annotated with @Singleton
bind(Service.class).to(ServiceImpl.class);
expose(ServiceImpl.class);
expose(Service.class);
```

Regards,
LL

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly bind ServiceImpl in the private module. The problem with your existing code is that it inherits the binding for ServiceImpl from the parent module. From the [PrivateModule](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html) docs,

> Private modules are implemented using parent injectors. When it can satisfy their dependencies, just-in-time bindings will be created in the root environment. Such bindings are shared among all environments in the tree.

Adding this line should fix the problem:

```
bind(ServiceImpl.class);
```

Comment: No that't not enough, you also need to expose the binding, as I said in the last post.

Comment: Nope! You only need to bind it. Exposing it from the private module is unnecessary (and somewhat defeats the point of private modules.) Test it for yourself to see.